# Getting Yaxis values in highchart after zoom

Tags: android, highcharts

I am using highcharts in android and the chart is loaded in a webview. I am using Webview built in zoom control. My problem is that when i zoom the chart, I want the see the y-axis values always. But when I zoom some part, it zooms that and the y-axis doesnt remain on screen anymore. So because of zoom it is hidden. But I want to show the Y-axis values even after we zoom it. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Some screen capture or preferably a jsFiddle would be helpful

Comment: Why not use Highcharts built in zoom control? This way it maintains the x/y axes.